# How to type a function that have properties and takes generic parameters

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Say I have a function that have a property `userId`, and there should be some constraint between `userId` and it's parameter and return type. Like:

```js
interface IMyfunc<T> {
    (item: T): T
    userId: T
}
```

and it's implementation is like:

```js
const func: IMyfunc<number> = a => a
func.userId = 1
```

So far so good, however, my doubt is that I can now only call `func` with number and can not call it with string or something else, since I **have to** explicitly bind its type parameter when I use `IMyfunc` interface.

So if I need `func` to take string parameter, I have to declare another function express that use `IMyfunc` with `string` type bound to its type parameter, what makes me think that the generic type here lost the meaning of **real generic**.

Is there any way that I can type a function which have properties and take generic parameters really generic?

Comment: you can achieve what you are calling "real generic" with const func: IMyfunc<any> = a => a, but you lose type safety. Typescript needs to know the type at the point of assigning the value

Comment: @DPro yes, so I'm wondering is there any way that we can make that kind of function real generic without losing the type safety.

Comment: Hmm, can you go through a use case?  Let's say I had a value of the "real generic" called `func`.  I understand that if you call `func(3)` you get a `number`, and if you call `func("a")` you get a `string`, but what is the type of `func.userId`?

Comment: @jcalz emm, if the implementation is `const func: IMyfunc<number> = a => { func.userId = a; return a }` maybe can make sense to your use case. Every time `func` get called, `func.userId` should be the type of `func`'s argument type.

Comment: What you are asking for is "*type state*" or "*type mutation*", where the type of a value can change based on how the value is used.  TypeScript can narrow the types of some values via control flow analysis, but there's no current way to represent arbitrary type mutation.  The upcoming [`asserts` feature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695) comes closer, but still wouldn't "stack" the way you want (presumably you want `func(0); const a = func.userId; func("a"); const b = func.userId` to infer `number` for `a` and `string` for `b`, but probably you'd get `never` for `b`.

Comment: Instead of mutating state, how about a more "fluent" or "chained" interface where `func(0)` returns a new function and you forget about the old function... something like `const func2 = func(0); const a = func2.userId; const func3 = func2("a"); const b = func3.userId;` where `a` is `number` and `b` is `string`?  This is more like how you'd do it in a functional programming language that didn't represent state mutations; instead of changing `func`, you get a new `func`.  If that is acceptable I'll write it up.  Otherwise, the answer here is "I don't think you can do this".

Comment: @jcalz Your explanation make sense to me. So I understand that what you say don't mutate type state means `func` should be something like: `function func<T>(a: T): IMyfunc<T> { const fn = (item: T) => item; fn.userId = a; return fn }`?

Comment: Please wrap it as an answer and I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question talks about "real" generics, which I would interpret to be arbitrary [generic values](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574), which are not currently supported in TypeScript.  The only generic value that TypeScript has is the generic function.

---

But what I think you are really asking for is "type state" or "type mutation", where the type of a value can change based on how the value is used.  The intent, I think, looks something like this:

```
func(4);
const n = func.userId; // n inferred as number
func("a");
const s = func.userId; // s inferred as string
func(false);
const b = func.userId; // b inferred as boolean
```

...where the type of `func.userId` changes depending on previous calls to `func()`.

Unfrotunately, while TypeScript can *narrow* the types of some values via [control flow analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#control-flow-based-type-analysis) (so a value of type `string | number` can be narrowed to a value of type `string`), there's no current way to represent *arbitrary* type mutation (e.g., a value of type `string` being changed to a value of type `number`).

The upcoming [`asserts` feature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695) (slated for [TS3.7](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33352)) should at least allow such narrowings to be represented in the type system, so you might be able to make `func(4)` narrow `func` from type `IMyfunc<unknown>` to `IMyfunc<number>`.  But you still probably won't be able to do the arbitrary mutation you're looking for.  Changing from `IMyfunc<number>` to `IMyfunc<string>` isn't narrowing; you'd first have to widen back to `IMyfunc<unknown>` somehow, and I don't think there's going to be any way to do that.

Something like your use case is discussed inside a [comment on the `asserts` feature pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695#issuecomment-523733928), and the can't-widen-back problem was [pointed out](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695#issuecomment-524097901).  Maybe eventually this will be doable, or something like this?  Not sure.

---

In any case, one of the main drivers of a static type system is that an expression has a static type that represents the set of possible values it can take, and the static type does not change.  This works well with functional programming techniques, which favor statelessness and immutability, and generally return a new value in situations where imperative programming might mutate an existing value.

If we change the code to do *that*, you get something more like the following:

```
type Func<T> = {
  userId: T;
  <U>(item: U): Func<U>;
};
```

Here the `Func<T>` is a type with a `userId` of type `T`, but when you call it as a function with a parameter of type `U`, it returns a `Func<U>`.  You can then discard the `Func<T>` and use the new `Func<U>` (which has a `userId` of type `U`).

One possible implementation would look like this:

```
function func<U>(item: U): Func<U> {
  const f = <T>(item: T) => func(item);
  return Object.assign(f, { userId: item });
}
```

This implementation is stateless; it never modifies itself or the item passed in.  You use it like this:

```
const f = func(4);
const n = f.userId; // number
console.log(n); // 4
```

And then you use `f` instead of `func`:

```
const g = f("a");
const s = g.userId; // string
console.log(s); // 1
```

But of course, in the above implementation, you *could* reuse `func()` because it's stateless:

```
const h = func(false);
const b = h.userId; // boolean
console.log(b); // false
```

In which case, you wouldn't really need all this complexity... and you'd just implement code like this:

```
function func<U>(item: U): { userId: U } {
  return { userId: item };
}

const f = func(4);
const n = f.userId; // 4
console.log(n); // 4

const g = func("a");
const s = g.userId; // string
console.log(s); // 1

const h = func(false);
const b = h.userId; // boolean
console.log(b); // false
```

At this point I've unraveled the situation to the extent that you've just got a function that returns a wrapped object.  I'd probably recommend this instead of anything with mutation, as it plays much more nicely with the type system.  But you know your use case better than I do.

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-6A7MCsHCCEh8Ww+GI5El1E3BWYyt4mvs+uZNU8iB8nPTIXCEUdmFHMpSm4yuUD8vK5eOdUQS0EMZAA)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can change the type of an object by calling a method on it (assigning a value to a field in you case). You could use the following though:

```
function setUserId<T>(userId: T, func: IMyfunc<unknown>): IMyfunc<T> {
  func.userId = userId;
  return <IMyfunc<T>>func;
}
```

Comment: There is an error when call `setUserId` with a `func` (say `const func: IMyfunc<number> = a => a`): "Argument of type 'IMyfunc<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IMyfunc<unknown>'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'."

Comment: But here is a new question for me that why the error message is "unknow is not assignable to type number" instead of "number is not assignable to type unknow"?

Comment: oh I see, because `item` is a function parameter, and `func: IMyfunc<unknown>` can take argument of `unknow` type, but `const func: IMyfunc<number> = a => a)` can only take argument of `number` type.