# Typescript assertion function for manipulating objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, assert

I want to manipulate an object with a function that parses all given keys to a number. In addition, the function should create the correct type for the object.

This is what I have until now:

```
type ReplaceStringWithNumber<T> = T extends string ? number : T

type ReplaceStringsWithNumbers<T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? ReplaceStringWithNumber<T[P]> : T[P]
}

export function parseIntIfSet<T extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends keyof T>(
  object: T | ReplaceStringsWithNumbers<T, K>,
  key: K
): asserts object is ReplaceStringsWithNumbers<T, K> {
  if (object[key]) {
    object[key] = Number(object[key]) as T[K]
  }
}
```

It looks good for now but when I test the function:

```
const p = {id: '1'}
parseIntIfSet(p, 'id')
// `p.id` is of type `never`, because `p` is of type `{id: string} & {id: number}`
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? A solution which works is to return a new object with the manipulated type, but this is not exactly what I want.

I am also not sure, why I need to use `T | ReplaceStringsWithNumbers<T, K>` in the parameters as I get an error if I just use `T`.

Comment: You can't do this; TypeScript does not allow arbitrary mutation of the type of a variable.  If `p` is initialized to be of type `{id: string}` then it will *always* be of type `{id: string}`.  You can *narrow* the *apparent* type of a variable, but since `string` and `number` have no overlap, then there's nothing you can narrow `p` to that is useful. Perhaps you could start `p` off as being of type `{id: string | number}`, but I doubt that's what you want either.  Is there a reason you don't want to just create a new object of the new type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015180/2887218)